# detect an 'a' tag with href attribute that equals the url of the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My task contains several steps:

1. hide all links in the page
2. detect a link element with href attribute that equals the current page url
3. show this element neighbors

The html I'm using is this:

```html
<div class="alllinkswrap">
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla1.com">1</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla2.com">2</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla3.com">3</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla4.com">4</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla5.com">5</a>
</div>
```

I've tried to hide all the link elements with `display: none`, and I want to show only 2 links that are on top and bottom of the current one. The jQuery code I use:

```js
  $(docment).ready(function(){
  var thispageurl = window.location.href;
   $(".alllinkswrap").children().each(function(){
    if (this.href.indexOf(thispageurl)) 
     {
       $(this).next().show();
       $(this).prev().show();
       }
   });
  });
```

I'm guessing the mistake is somewhere in `$(this).next` and so on part. But still new to jQuery. Can you detect the problem?

Comment: So, if the current site is `blabla3.com` you want to show `blabla2.com` and `blabla4.com`?

Comment: If `window.location.href == this.href`, `.indexOf()` will return `0`; your condition will be 'falsey'.

Comment: Sure. For example sake let's have it this way

Comment: @George `window.location.href` will always be the full URL, beginning with `http://domain.com/path`. So `indexOf` can never return 0.

Comment: @Barmar But the `href` property of these anchor tags will be the resolved URL, I.e: `http://domain.com/blabla1.com` (in this case)? Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @George That's what I said

Comment: @Barmar No, you said `window.location.href`, I'm talking about the `href` property of the anchor elements.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original**

your indexOf(...) needs to check for not -1, it will return -1 when `thispageurl` was not found `in this.href`. Or you could check that it equals 0, because when the target link is found it should be found at index 0.

**Update**

If you do want to check for equality of the current URL and the target href, we need to make use of the `==` or `===` comparrision in Javascript. This is because we run into problems when pages are in subidrectories or if you are on the domain. For example:

If `thispageurl` = `http://url.com` and `this.href` = `http://url.com/page1.html` the using `this.href.indexOf(thispageurl)` would return 0, but it would not be correct. If we reversed the index of for `thispageurl.indexOf(this.href)` in that scenario, `.indexOf()` returns -1. Likewise, if we flip `thispageurl` and `this.href` to `http://url.com/page1.html` and `http://url.com` respectively, we run into a similar situation depending on which we are taking an indexOf.

So I Updated the following code to check for equality of string values.

```js
var thispageurl = window.location.href;
$(".alllinkswrap").children().each(function(){$(this).hide()})

$(".alllinkswrap").children().each(function(){
  if (this.href === thispageurl) 
  {
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).prev().show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alllinkswrap">
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla1.com">1</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla2.com">2</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="http://stacksnippets.net/js">3</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla4.com">4</a>
  <a class="allproductsurls" href="blabla5.com">5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you have some extra code somewhere? Running the above snippet shows links 2 and 4, this is your desired functionality?

Comment: The code snippet above is fired on document ready (even though it is not in the code snippet), make sure you keep that portion of your code

Comment: Well, your code obviously works, so , i'll try to figure out what's happening in mine.

Comment: hmm, are your links dynamically generated or hard coded?

Comment: dynamically generated

Comment: Depending on how you generate the links and the timing of generation, your javascript/jquery code might be executed too soon, if possible try wrapping the above code in a function and then executing that function at the end of the code used to create the links.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `thispageurl.indexOf(...)`?

Comment: @Barmar, I don't see why it couldn't be `thispageurl.indexOf(...)`. If the `thispageurl` and the `href` value are the same, wouldn't they be interchangeable, that both `.indexOf(...)` statements would return 0? Thinking about it a little longer, if we were truly checking for equality, wouldn't we want to be doing a `==` or even an `===` operation instead? If `thispageurl` = `http://url.com` and a.href = `http://url.com/page1.html` you would be correct. But, if reversed and `thispageurl` = `http://url.com/page1.html` and a.href = `http://url.com` the original would be correct.

Comment: Good point. I keep thinking that `this.href` should just be the attribute value, not the full URI. That would be correct if it were `$(this).attr('href')`.

Comment: @Barmar, That is also a good point. Would you advise that I include that tidbit of information in the answer; that `this.href` returns the full URI/URL regardless of whether it is written in the context of absolute/relative where as $(this).attr('href') returns just the attribute value?

Comment: It may be sufficient that it's in the comment.